# How to acheive this effect (Rounded Corners & Drop Down Menu)

Tags: css

I am trying to find out how I can replicate this effect as seen on [Aviary](http://www.aviary.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't listen to the image lovers, I've solved this very problem with no images or extra markup on two occasions:

[The most semantic way of making this container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375978/the-most-semantic-way-of-making-this-container/4384017#4384017)

[CSS to create curved corner between two elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601317/css-to-create-curved-corner-between-two-elements/4622256#4622256)

This about "Discover creations" as if it were a rounded green button.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this is to use an image; [my site](http://www.jamwaffles.co.uk) uses images. It may be possible with CSS3, but the markup would be horrid!

James

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

This will give you a starter for 10. The rounded corner is probably an image.

Comment: I was looking at that tut, except they use a straight line/connection without rounded corners at the join

Comment: Indeed they do - but if you use a bit of absolutely positioned CSS within the drop down div, you should be able to align a curved image over that.

Answer (score 0):

According to firebug, they use an image there http://images.aviary.com/images/layout/nav/link.gif.

A messier way to do it would be to use rounded corners so the green part has rounded corners and is positioned over the gray part.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 25 different ways of making rounded corners. Pick one. :)
http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/

(It's not actually 25 techniques, but links to 25 different sites that explain how to do it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty quick and easy with javascript if you have just a few of them.

[See Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aRounded_Corners)

---